# How to set default parameters In case a user does not type in the other one

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <iostream>

class Person {
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Person &person);
    std::string name;
    int age;
public:
    std::string get_name () {return name;}
    int get_age() {return age;}
    Person() : name{"Unknown"}, age{0} {}
    Person(std::string name, int age) : name{name}, age{age} {}
};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Person &person) {
    os << person.name << ": " << person.age;
    return os;
}

int main () {
    Person Austin{"Austin", 12}; 
}
```

I am trying to have it where for my name I type in "Austin", but If I don't type in age it will automatically make it a 0 because I did not enter a age.

Comment: `Person(std::string name, int age = 0)` ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since C++11 you can take advantage of ***delegating constructors***: you can provide an additional constructor overload that takes only an `std::string` for the name and *delegates* to the existing constructor that accepts the two arguments, `std::string` and `int`. Then, just pass `0` as the second argument to the delegated constructor:

```
Person(std::string name) : Person(name, 0) {}
```

That is, `Person(std::string)` would be the *delegating constructor*, and the existing `Person(std::string, int)` the *delegated* one.

---

Another approach would be to use a ***default argument*** for the second parameter of the existing constructor that accepts both an `std::string` and an `int`:

```
Person(std::string name, int age = 0) : name{name}, age{age} {}
```

The drawback to this latter approach is that the default argument is always compiled directly in client code. This would make recompiling the client code necessary whenever a default argument changes.

Comment: See the thing is lets say I enter 0 for my age and no name. I would like it to say Unknown, but I tried the code and it gives me an error.

Comment: @austinvan295 For that to work, add another delegating constructor for that case: `Person(int age): Person("Unknown", age) {}`. The principle is the same as explained.

Comment: I wouldn't want to make two delegating constructors one for name and one for age. I feel like there is another way where I can put it all in one constructor, but I just forgot how.

Comment: Is there no other way where I can fit both of my values into one constructor rather than creating two?

Comment: @austinvan295 You can arrange the constructors, so that there is **only one constructor with a non-empty *body***, i.e., the one of `Person(std::string, int)`. The remaining constructor can simply delegate to this one, and they all can have an **empty body**. You can think of this as those delegating constructors as just "entry points" for the more general constructor, which will contain all the logic.

Comment: @austinvan295 Note that this can also be applied to your *default constructor*. You can just define it as: `Person(): Person("Unknown", 0) {}`

Comment: @austinvan295 there is no way to do what you want with only 1 constructor.  C++ is type-safe, and argument order matters.  So you can't define a constructor `(string, int)` and then pass it only an `int`, it just doesn't work that way. But you could define a constructor `(int, string = "")` for that, but then you couldn't pass it only a string. Using additional constructors with different signatures (whether you delegate them or not) is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

C++ has default parameters, use them.

```
Person(std::string name, int age=0) : name{name}, age{age} {}
```

Does exactly what you asked for

```
int main () {
    Person Austin{"Austin"}; 
    std::cout << Austin << std::endl; //prints out "Austin: 0"
}
```